# Can't transform tiff image to jpg

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

i'm trying to create a simple script that transforms all the tiff images in a directory to jpg, but I get this error:

> cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG

Here's my code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

yourpath = os.getcwd()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(yourpath, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
        if os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, name))[1].lower() == ".tiff":
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, name))[0] + ".jpg"):
                print ("A jpeg file already exists for %s" % name)
            # If a jpeg is *NOT* present, create one from the tiff.
            else:
                outfile = os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, name))[0] + ".jpg"
                try:
                    im = Image.open(os.path.join(root, name))
                    print ("Generating jpeg for %s" % name)
                    im.thumbnail(im.size)
                    im.save(outfile, "JPEG", quality=100)
                except Exception as e:
                    print (e)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

RGBA stands for "red, green, blue, alpha", where alpha is the opacity (allowing for partially transparent images). JPEG doesn't support alpha channels, so you have to do a conversion like this:

```
 im = im.convert("RGB")
```

I'm assuming that none of your input images are grayscale, or if they are, that you don't mind converting them to RGB as well. Otherwise, check `im.mode` before doing the conversion.

Comment: I had already tried that, but it dosn't work, the image isn't created

Answer (score 0):

it is a bit late, but following would work:

```
im.convert("RGB").save(outfile, "JPEG", quality=100)
```